# ng2-ace-editor doesn't show colour and folded due to language(mode) fail

Tags: xml, typescript, angular7, ace-editor, xml-editor

I try to show an XML editor with proper editing experiance. Only thing I'm expecting is proper coloring, indentaion and folding. I used ng2-ace-editor lib. seems due to language selection fail coloring and folding are not working here.

---

component.ts

### [this is the code in component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juped.png)

component.html

```
  <ace-editor
[(text)]="xmlToView"
[options]="options"
[durationBeforeCallback]="1000"
[theme]="eclipse"
[mode]="'ace/mode/xml'">
```

---

Result

[sasc This is the result I get. I want to show the folding as well as color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1i6l.png)

Comment: Hey @Upz Aiz - welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you post your code directly in the question, please, rather than as links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code example in https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor readme,  you need to use `[mode]="'xml'"` without the `ace/mode` part.